# nginx proxy_pass of different subdomains to different locations within one server block

Tags: nginx

The typical way of reverse-proxying different subdomains to different places with Nginx is to install a unique server for each subdomain, like this:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain1.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://hostname1:port1;
    }
}
server {
    server_name subdomain2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://hostname2:port2;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result within one single server block (e.g. server_name .example.com, without any specified subdomain), by specifying different locations within that server block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First, set up a `map` to map domains into `proxy_pass` destinations:

```
map $host $dest {
    www1.example.com 192.168.10.10:8001;
    www2.example.com 192.168.10.11:8002;
    default 192.168.10.12;
}

server {
    server_name *.example.com;

    proxy_pass http://$dest;
}
```

When nginx receives a request, it goes to `proxy_pass` directive. Then it resolves `$dest` using the `map`, which maps different virtual host names to destinations. Then nginx proxies the request using the resolved destination.

Remember to set up the default destination properly. Every public web server receives requests for all kinds of domain names. Typically you want to return 404 on unknown virtual hosts.

Comment: Dear @tero, I have to come back to this. Your solution works for simple 1:1 transfers. However, e.g. `https://icinga.example.com` should be proxy_passed to `http://10.10.10.7/icingaweb2`, whereas `https://mail.example.com` should go to `http://10.10.10.9/iredmail/mail` etc. I seem to understand that I need to define location blocks, but those won't work with subdomains. Do you have further advice?

Comment: update. It seems that proxy_pass to a variable requires an explicit rewrite rule. I am playing around with such rules but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Did you try just using different destination URL in the `map`? `icinga.example.com 10.10.10.7/icingaweb2` as the `map` line? Also, you need to set up the base URL properly in each application configuration.

Comment: if `icinga.example.com` is mapped to `10.10.10.7/icingaweb2`, the client is sent to the non-existing page `https://icinga.example.com/icingaweb2/authentication/login`

Comment: Are you sure you have set the root URL of `icinga` application correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify different locations then it won't be the same result as you have the same `location /` in two `server` blocks.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. I may have expressed myself ambiguously. The goal is to reverse-proxy various subdomains, each one of which will be served by a different internal server. Rather than installing a number of individual nginx servers, which makes the configuration unwieldy, I was wondering whether I can specify a single "wildcard server" which will then direct the requests to the correct internal servers depending on the subdomains requested.

Comment: You can use a variable as `proxy_pass` parameter See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743609/dynamic-proxy-pass-to-var-with-nginx-1-0

Comment: I now did use a variable, but it turns out that I then need to explicitly declare a rewrite rule. I have yet to figure out how to do that correctly.